# Orthogonal complement of the solution vector in $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, projection-matrices

In $Ax=b$, if I look $x$ as a projection of $A$ onto the subspace that $x$ spans and $b$ is the projected result, then is it possible to calculate some sort of "orthogonal complement" to the subspace that $x$ spans? Formally, is it possible to calculate a matrix $M$ such that $M^\top x = \vec{0}$?

This question was raised from my recent thinking of SVD. Suppose we have $X=U\Sigma V^\top$ as SVD formulation. We usually calculate $U$ and $V$ naturally by eigendecompositions. However, if I want to specify the eigenvectors that correspond to the largest singular value, namely $u_1$ and $v_1$ to some predefined value instead of the naturally calculated ones, is it possible to sort out the rest of vectors in $U$ and $V$ according to the predefined $u_1$ and $v_1$ while preserving the setup $X=U\Sigma V^\top$?

I want to use some iterative methods to calculate the eigenvectors that correspond to the second/third largest singular values, with the largest eigenvectors $u_1$ and $v_1$ predefined in some way instead of the actual ones. Does this idea make sense?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: None of this makes much sense. $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ that is hopefully equal to $b$, the affine solution space is parallel to the kernel and thus orthogonal to the co-kernel. If $X$ is given, its SVD is fixed up to sign changes, it is not clear what you want to achieve by changing the first left and right singular vectors. Do you want to construct a new $X$ that somehow mixes the old $X$ with the new singular vectors?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your comment! I wanted to use modified SVD to do some tasks similar to PCA, but with a predefined major component/direction of most variance so that hopefully the rest of the components can be adjusted accordingly. (For example, if I let the first major component to be defined as a sparse vector, I would want the second vector to be orthogonal to the predefined first one. If I further let the second one to be defined as a sparse vector, then I want the third component to be orthogonal to the first two.)

Comment: So you want some kind of sparse and thus in general incomplete SVD. I'm not sure if that is possible at all, but sparse QR exists. Some classes of sparse matrices can be reordered into a nearly block-diagonal shape, doing the SVD on the diagonal blocks only should result in a decomposition with sparse orthogonal matrices, but the middle matrix will not be diagonal, with luck it will be dominantly diagonal.